# Should [azure-machine-learning-service] be renamed as [azure-machine-learning]?

Tags: discussion, tags

Looks like Azure Machine Learning Service has been rebranded into [Azure Machine Learning](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/services/machine-learning/) (...without the *service*).

Old links like https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/service/, also referenced in [azure-machine-learning-service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-machine-learning-service) redirect to https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/.

Azure ML Studio (which on SO is [azure-machine-learning-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-machine-learning-studio)) still exists as a separate product: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/compare-azure-ml-to-studio-classic.

Should [azure-machine-learning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-machine-learning) be created and [azure-machine-learning-service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-machine-learning-service) made a synonym of it
or
should [azure-machine-learning-service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-machine-learning-service) be renamed as [azure-machine-learning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-machine-learning)?

Comment: Is it still a service, though? If a marketing team changes the name of a tree in the forest, does it make a sound?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[azure-machine-learning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-machine-learning) became a synonym of [azure-machine-learning-service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-machine-learning-service) https://stackoverflow.com/tags/azure-machine-learning-service/synonyms in June 2020.